# No string translation of plural token using ngettext

Tags: flask, internationalization, jinja2, gettext

I am trying to translate this ngettext. However I am still getting the english version. I can get it work using gettext. Any idea?

```
{{ngettext('%(num)s Movie found while searching.', '%(num)s Movies found while searching.', qty_movies)}}
```

---

messages.po

```
msgid "%(num)s Movie found while searching."
msgstr "%(num)s Filme encontrado na procura."

msgid "%(num)s Movies found while searching."
msgstr "%(num)s Filmes encontrados na procura."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research [here](https://github.com/davewhiteland/flask-babel-test), this is what I need

```
msgid "%(num)s Movie found while searching."
msgid_plural "%(num)s Movies found while searching."
msgstr[0] "%(num)s Filme encontrado na procura."
msgstr[1] "%(num)s Filmes encontrados na procura."
```